# Django custom login never authenticates why?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I'm trying to create a custom login form. Below is what I have so far. My issues is that no matter what I do the login never authenticates. Even tho I have the correct email and password I always get:

**Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.**

I think it's because I'm checking for email and password.

****This is my form. ****

```
class EmailAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email Address'))
    redirect_url = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)

    def __init__(self, host=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.host = host
        super(EmailAuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is my view.**

```
class AccountAuthView(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    form_class = EmailAuthenticationForm
    redirect_field_name = 'next'

    def get_form_class(self):
        return self.form_class

    def form_valid(self, form):
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(form.cleaned_data['redirect_url'])

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        return super(AccountAuthView, self).get(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Are you really sure the credentials are correct? How did you create the user in the first pace?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman yes I think its because my form extends AuthenticationForm where it's checking user name and password not email and password?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to customise the user model. By default it will certainly be trying to authenticate the username and password. Not the email address.

Comment: @aychedee how can I do this in the class view?

Comment: I don't think you can. I create my own user model according to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done very easily first create an authentication backend:

**backend.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    """
    Email Authentication Backend
    """

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """ Authenticate a user based on email address as the user name. """
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then in **settings.py:**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('backends.EmailAuthBackend',)
```

Last make sure your form has the email field:

```
<form action="." method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {% for field in form %}
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <div class="label-wrapper">
        {% if field.name == "username" %}
          Email address
        {% else %}
          {{ field.label_tag }}
        {% endif %}
        {% if field.field.required %}<span class="required">*</span>{% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="value-wrapper">
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="submit-wrapper">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: PS. also don't forget AUTH_USER_MODEL if your using get_user_model as in above example I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Django has a [Full Example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) to show how to do customized authentication.